# Azure DocumentDb id

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I was playing with the azure Document Db and came accross a problem or rather confusing about Ids. I know that DocumentDb generates a "lowercase" "id" property for every document, this is fine with me, but I cant seem to figure out how to get this "id" when using the .net client. my code looks like below

```
 public class Company
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } // this somehow does not get mapped to the "id" in the document.
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

    }
```

so when i query like

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<Company>(collection.DocumentsLink).ToList();
```

the id property is not mapped. I think I havent understood the ID concept in document db and how it maps to your entities properly. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: main question, id property mapped when your Company modify by id instead of Id? no? so , it is not your Id. It is DocumentDb database id.

Comment: I have tried to  rename it to lowercase id it still does not bring it back.

Comment: i suppose that... lets check whats wrong. could you please modify question with your source code?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your company entity to

```
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public String Id { get; set; }
```

This will load the documentdb generated Id, into the id field.

Let me know if that doesnt work.

Comment: This works. But also means that I have to change my model to adapt to persistence layer.

Comment: You need to change you model anyway since it's generated by DocumentDB you cannot have a setter for it.

Comment: @Darren Nope. An `id` is generated when it's not provided. One can always provide an `id`. Just need to ensure the case is correctly set.

Comment: This helped me solve the opposite where by I needed to set the Id field of an object going into documentDB. Basically you need to match the name of the id field of the documentDB record.